# Display html text in uitextview

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

How can I display HTML text in textview?

For example,

```
string &lt;h1&gt;Krupal testing &lt;span style="font-weight:
bold;"&gt;Customer WYWO&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;
```

Suppose text is bold so it display in textview as bold string
but I want display normal text.  Is this possible in the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use a UIWebView on iOS 5-.

On iOS 6+ you can use `UITextView.attributedString`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20996085 for how.

---

There's also an *undocumented* `-[UITextView setContentToHTMLString:]` method. Do not use this if you want to submit to AppStore.

Comment: App will be rejected for using undocumented methods......... I already experience it.

Comment: is this method still undocumented in ios 7?

Comment: @Ajeet If you can't find it in http://developer.apple.com then it's undocumented.

Comment: Couldn't find it in Class References. So, i guess its still undocumented. :(

Comment: If it's an HTML string use:
[(webView) loadHTMLString:(HTMLString) baseURL:nil];

Comment: Hi, How to calculate height of text view? I do not want text view to be scrolling. I used textView.contensize. Did not worked.

Comment: It works. But I also need to show HTML table content. When I tried, it shows only the content of <th> tag. How to show HTML table content?

Answer (score 240):

Use following block of code for ios 7+.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<h1>Header</h1><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Some <em>text</em></p><img src='http://blogs.babble.com/famecrawler/files/2010/11/mickey_mouse-1097.jpg' width=70 height=100 />";
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
          initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
               options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
    documentAttributes: nil
                 error: nil
];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Hi, How to calculate height of text view? I do not want text view to be scrolling. I used textView.contensize. Did not worked.

Comment: How could I change the font of the string? Using addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName seems reset all the font(bold).

Comment: if i want to set the img src from bundle how can we call it? i tried like this but it doesn't work  @"<div style='font-size:14px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;'>Getting started with the application<p><strong>Homepage</strong><br>Upon opening the application, you will be taken to the homepage, from where can you navigate to the various sections of the app, by clicking on the navigation buttons. </p><img src='images/sample.jpg' style='float:right; margin:10px; max-width:170px;' /></div>"

Comment: This is a great answer. I want to add that what messed me up was trying to put string literals inside of the html instead of what's shown above. Wrong (what I was doing): html = @"<a href=@\"www.espn.com\">ESPN</a>"; Right: html = @"<a href='www.espn.com'>ESPN</a>";

Comment: this is working like anything, but if i place this this piece of code in viewdidload method view loading very slow. any help?

Comment: To change the font, change `NSAttributedString` to `NSMutableAttributedString` and add `[attributedString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];`

Comment: To automagically size it  `tv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, HUGE, 1);
    [tv sizeToFit]; `

Comment: @Durgaprasad to modify string's style you can create mutable copy and set your attributes to it:
`NSMutableAttributedString *mString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:attributedString];
            [mString addAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, mString.length)];`

Comment: Hi, anyone use this method in app and got approved on app store? When I use this conversion I got a debug message complaining "dlopen(/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI", it has private framework involved?

Comment: @GastonM Thanks a ton.. it perfectly solved the problem

Comment: images from url are not loading in it. is it the limitation or any modification required for this

Comment: if we use this method then any problem while uploading on app store ?

Comment: @MaheshCheliya I did not face any problem while upload the app on app store. There should not be any problem. Good luck to you.

Comment: @jeswang I am facing the same problem. Did you the get solution to it?

Comment: @BHUPI Adding attribute through addAttribute resets font of all the text. It doesn't respect bold tag and all of HTML. How to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: @Durgaprasad Guess you have found the answer after 4 years but in case you didn't.
let height = label.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height

Answer (score 58):

For **Swift 4**, **Swift 4.2:** and **Swift 5**

```
let htmlString = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body {
                    background-color : rgb(230, 230, 230);
                    font-family      : 'Arial';
                    text-decoration  : none;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>A title</h1>
            <p>A paragraph</p>
            <b>bold text</b>
        </body>
    </html>
    """

let htmlData = NSString(string: htmlString).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)

let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]

let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)

textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

For **Swift 3**:

```
let htmlString = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                body {
                    background-color : rgb(230, 230, 230);
                    font-family      : 'Arial';
                    text-decoration  : none;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>A title</h1>
            <p>A paragraph</p>
            <b>bold text</b>
        </body>
    </html>
    """

let htmlData = NSString(string: htmlString).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)

let attributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: htmlData!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Is there any way to add external css to html attributed String @pableiros

Comment: @Mansuu.... You have to read the css file from your bundle: `let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "styles", ofType: "css")`, get the content `let content = try! String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` and add it to the html String

Comment: Thanks @pableiros It worked, but not the way I want. My external css imports bootstrap.min.css. It does not work when I applying css to UItextView by getting it's content.

Comment: thanks a lot it works for my for the swift 3 :)  keep it up

Answer (score 20):

BHUPI's answer is correct, but if you would like to combine your custom font from UILabel or UITextView with HTML content, you need to correct your html a bit:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<b>Bold</b><br><i>Italic</i><p> <del>Deleted</del><p>List<ul><li>Coffee</li><li type='square'>Tea</li></ul><br><a href='URL'>Link </a>";

htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:@"<style>body{font-family:'YOUR_FONT_HERE'; font-size:'SIZE';}</style>"];
/*Example:

 htmlString = [htmlString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx;}</style>",_myLabel.font.fontName,_myLabel.font.pointSize]];
*/
 NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                      initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                           options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
                documentAttributes: nil
                             error: nil
            ];
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

You can see the difference on the picture  below:
[image]

Comment: Can you put Apple's system font here?

Comment: I want to add external css, how can I do that ? @David

Answer (score 12):

You can have a look the OHAttributedLabel classes, I used these to overcome this kind of problem with my textField. In this they have overridden the drawRect method to obtain the required style.

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Comment: How can OHAttributedLabel display ul li tags?

Answer (score 9):

My first response was made before iOS 7 introduced explicit support for displaying attributed strings in common controls. You may now set `attributedText` of `UITextView` to an `NSAttributedString` created from HTML content using:

```
-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSDictionary *)options documentAttributes:(NSDictionary **)dict error:(NSError **)error
```

[- initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error: (Apple Doc)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:)

*Original answer, preserved for history:*

Unless you use a `UIWebView`, your solution will rely directly on `CoreText`. As ElanthiraiyanS points out, some open source projects have emerged to simplify rich text rendering. I would recommend <strike>[NSAttributedString-Additions-For-HTML](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML)</strike> (**Edit:** the project has been supplanted [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)), which features classes to generate and display attributed strings from HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Answer has fitted to me that from BHUPI.

The code transfer to swift as below:

Pay attention **"allowLossyConversion: false"**

if you set the value to true, it will show pure text.

```
let theString = "<h1>H1 title</h1><b>Logo</b><img src='http://www.aver.com/Images/Shared/logo-color.png'><br>~end~"

        let theAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: theString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)

        UITextView_Message.attributedText = theAttributedString
```

Comment: `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` is correct, because NSString is Unicode-encoded, not UTF8. In case of CJK character, you won't get right answer.

Answer (score 3):

For Swift3

```
    let theString = "<h1>H1 title</h1><b>Logo</b><img src='http://www.aver.com/Images/Shared/logo-color.png'><br>~end~"

    let theAttributedString = try! NSAttributedString(data: theString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!,
        options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
        documentAttributes: nil)

    UITextView_Message.attributedText = theAttributedString
```

Answer (score 1):

For some cases UIWebView is a good solution. Because:

- it displays tables, images, other files
- it's fast (comparing with NSAttributedString: NSHTMLTextDocumentType)
- it's out of the box

Using NSAttributedString can lead to crashes, if html is complex or contains tables ([so example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759741/uitextview-crash-in-ios-8-with-attributed-string-containing-a-table))

For loading text to web view you can use the following snippet (just example):

```
func loadHTMLText(_ text: String?, font: UIFont) {
        let fontSize = font.pointSize * UIScreen.screens[0].scale
        let html = """
        <html><body><span style=\"font-family: \(font.fontName); font-size: \(fontSize)\; color: #112233">\(text ?? "")</span></body></html>
        """
        self.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use one more way. Three20 library offers a method through which we can construct a styled textView. You can get the library here: http://github.com/facebook/three20/

The class TTStyledTextLabel has a method called textFromXHTML: I guess this would serve the purpose. But it would be possible in readonly mode. I don't think it will allow to write or edit HTML content.

There is also a question which can help you regarding this: [HTML String content for UILabel and TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261654/html-string-content-for-uilabel-and-textview)

I hope its helpful.

Answer (score -3):

NSDoc save the text file in a string to an html file then simultaneously load it into a webview that is in the same place as your UITextView..