# Highlighting search result in UITableView cell iOS Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, highlight, searchbar

I have implemented a search bar in a `TableView`. Now I want to highlight the result. For example, if I have typed two letters then those two letters should be highlighted in the resultant `TableView` that drops down from the search bar. Can anyone help me to do this? I know I should use custom cells for this, but am lost implementing it.

Comment: what have you looked at so far? attributed strings? show your current code

Comment: @Wain no i haven't done anything yet. but saw the code for attributed strings in objective c. couldn't understand.. can you help me with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight the searched text in UITableView using UISearchBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555619/highlight-the-searched-text-in-uitableview-using-uisearchbar)

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it doesn't have elaborate answer

Answer (score 14):

> Here is the second way to attribute text in tableview
>
> ```
>    let initialtext =   "Hello World"
>     let attrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: initialtext)
>
> let range: NSRange = (initialtext as NSString).rangeOfString(("World" , options:NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch])
>
>
>     attrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: range)
>
>
>     cell!.textLabel?.attributedText = attrString
> ```

Answer (score 11):

@Vijay has a good, correct answer for this post.

I modified this slightly for my own purposes (bolding the text in my search results) by creating a function that accepts the `searchString` and the string you want to modify - the 
`resultString` - and returns an `attributedString` that can be applied to a `UILabel`.

I also had this check for the `lowercaseString` attribute, so that regardless of what I typed into my search bar, my string would match the characters rather than the case (this requirement may be different, depending on your use-case).

```
func boldSearchResult(searchString: String, resultString: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

    let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: resultString)
    let pattern = searchString.lowercaseString
    let range: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, resultString.characters.count)

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())

    regex.enumerateMatchesInString(resultString.lowercaseString, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: range) { (textCheckingResult, matchingFlags, stop) -> Void in
        let subRange = textCheckingResult?.range
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.customBoldedFontNameWithSize(15.0), range: subRange!)
    }

    return attributedString

}
```

**Note**: I had a custom bolded font to work with, but you could always use `UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(fontSize: CGFloat)` or something like that to get a similar effect.

Then, just add the result to your label by doing (some variation of):

```
cell.myCustomLabel.attributedText = boldSearchResult(mySearchText, resultString: textForBolding)
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 5 version of Vijayvir's answer:

```swift
let initialtext = "Hello, World!"

let attrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: initialtext)

let range = (initialtext as NSString).range(of: "World", options: .caseInsensitive)

attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)

cell.textLabel?.attributedText = attrString
```

Update 2020:
Here's a simple `String` extension you can use to easily make an attributed string.

```swift
extension String {

    func highlightText(
        _ text: String,
        with color: UIColor,
        caseInsensitivie: Bool = false,
        font: UIFont = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)) -> NSAttributedString
    {
        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        let range = (self as NSString).range(of: text, options: caseInsensitivie ? .caseInsensitive : [])
        attrString.addAttribute(
            .foregroundColor,
            value: color,
            range: range)
        attrString.addAttribute(
            .font,
            value: font,
            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length))
        return attrString
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could achieve this by find the search term string range from your result string and adding attributed string at that range. Find the sample code below,

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *searchTerm = /* SEARCH_TERM */;
NSString *resultText = /* YOUR_RESULT_TEXT */;

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:resultText];

NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", searchTerm];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, resultText.length);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:resultText options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor redColor]
                             range:subStringRange];
}];
```

**Swift (TESTED)**

```
let searchTerm = "" /* SEARCH_TERM */
let resultText = "" /* YOUR_RESULT_TEXT */
let attributedString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: resultText)
let pattern = "(\(searchTerm))"
let range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, resultText.characters.count)

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression( pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
regex.enumerateMatchesInString(
     resultText,
     options: NSMatchingOptions(),
     range: range,
     usingBlock: {
        (textCheckingResult, matchingFlags, stop) -> Void in
           let subRange = textCheckingResult?.range
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: subRange!)
            }
        )
```

Comment: @GaneshKumar Edited my answer.

Comment: i have used predicates for filtering. Where should i use the code.. In the filter? or in the cellforRowatIndexPath?

Comment: @GaneshKumar If you are using table view to render your search result then you have to use this as `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @GaneshKumar If my answer is useful then accept it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94327/discussion-between-ganesh-kumar-and-vijay).

Comment: @GaneshKumar Accept my answer if it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to keep it as slim as possible. 
The function returns an attributed string with searchText occurrences in bold.
Swift 4.2+

```
  private func boldedString(with baseString: String, searchString: String, fontSize: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString? {
    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive) else {
        return nil
    }

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString)
    let boldFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: .bold)
    regex
      .matches(in: baseString, options: .withTransparentBounds,
               range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.utf16.count))
      .forEach {
        attributedString.addAttributes([.font: boldFont], range: $0.range)
    }
    return attributedString
  }
```

In the cell you will need to add code like this for configuration:

```
func configure(with text: String, searchText: String?) {
  if let boldedAddress = boldedString(with: text,
                                      searchString: searchText,
                                      fontSize: titleLabel.font.pointSize) {
    titleLabel.attributedText = boldedAddress
  } else {
    titleLabel.text = locationInfo.location.address
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with escaped characters Like (**{}[]()'"**) this solution written in SWIFT 5.

```
func generateAttributedString(with searchTerm: String, targetString: NSAttributedString) -> NSAttributedString? {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: targetString)
    do {

        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:  NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: searchTerm).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).folding(options: .regularExpression, locale: .current), options: .caseInsensitive)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: targetString.string.utf16.count)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.clear, range: range)


        for match in regex.matches(in: targetString.string.folding(options: .regularExpression, locale: .current), options: .withTransparentBounds, range: range) {
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
        }
        return attributedString
    } catch {
        NSLog("Error creating regular expresion: \(error)")
        return nil
    }
}
```