# Highlight search letter in TableView - ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, highlight, uisearchbardelegate

I have implemented a `UISearchBar` in a `UITableView`. Now I want to highlight the result of search list. For example, if I am typing three letters then those letters should be highlighted in the resultant TableView that drops down from the search bar.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542905/highlighting-search-result-in-uitableview-cell-ios-swift

Comment: Please provide some code. What is your approach? What is going right? What is going wrong? Expected output? Current output?

Comment: Hey, and welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid no appropriate answer can be given with this little information about what you need. In stackoverflow, try to ask questions with what you have done, post your code and screenshots of the issue, that way we all can understand better

Answer (score 0):

func boldSearchResult(searchString: String, resultString: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {

```
let attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: resultString)
let Desiredpattern = searchString.lowercaseString
let range: NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, resultString.characters.count)

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(Desiredpattern: Desiredpattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())

regex.enumerateMatchesInString(resultString.lowercaseString, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: range) { (textCheckingResult, matchingFlags, stop) -> Void in
    let Range = textCheckingResult?.range
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.customBoldedFontNameWithSize(15.0), range: Range!)
}

return attributedString
```

}

```
cell.YourLabel.attributedText = boldSearchResult(mySearchText, resultString: textForBolding)
```

Comment: Works for me
Thank you!

Comment: Deviyani Swami I can See there is no upvote or mark you might have marked the wrong one