# Format web links in a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I know that I can put a link in a UITextView such as "http://stackoverflow.com/" and have it auto detected. I want to know if there is a way to set the UITextView so that the link appears as "Visit StackOverflow" in the UITextView, or if I have to use a UIWebView to do that. I'm fairly sure that I have to use a UIWebView, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't do that, and from reading other posts it appears that there is an undocumented method, but that would get you app rejected (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview). Why not simply use a web view? As that is what it is designed for! ;)

Jonathan

Comment: The UITextView is in a subclass of UITableViewCell, and part of a module that creates a table view based on reading in an xml file. I would prefer not to have to create another subclass of UITableViewCell and choose which table view cell to use based on the content of the xml file, but it looks like that's what I'm going to have to do. Thanks for your help!