# How can I make a scrollable label that contains clickable links?

Tags: ios, uilabel, rss-reader

In my app I've created a small RSS feed reader that shows the titles of the news. I've simply put the titles in a single string and I'm showing them in a scrolling [MarqueeLabel](https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel). I'd like to make the titles clickable to show the linked news and I've tried to do so following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630187/1312527), but the string is not interactable at all, even if it is highlighted as a hyperlink.

Is there an easy way to make it work? I've tried to look if there are libraries that combine both the scrolling and the linking functionalities, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[marqueeLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    MarqueeLabel *marqueeLabel =  (MarqueeLabel*) [gesture view];
    NSLog(@"Clicked Link would be %@",marqueeLabel.text);

}
```

NB:Just add UITapGestureRecognizer to your desired label and handle it