# Make text matched with NSRegularExpression clickable in UITextView

Tags: ios, regex, swift, uitextview, nsregularexpression

I have a `UITextView` and using `NSRegularExpression`. I'm finding names in my text view. So I'm able to highlight matches using this code:

```
for match in matches as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
    let matchRange = match.range
    attributedText.addAttribute(NSStrokeColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(), range:  matchRange)
}
```

I want to make it clickable and pass its text to a new view controller. Or maybe change it to a `UIButton` with the same text and add a segue to the new view controller. I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextView` doesn't really have functionality for that. You could try your `UIButton` approach but you'll have trouble with links that wrap on multiple lines.

Two possible solutions:

1. You may be able to force its URL handling functionality to do what you want - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21629784/1445366). This will depend on your `NSRegularExpression`.
2. You might want to try replacing your text view with [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) or a similar third-party library that handles this for you. I think this is the most flexible option, and my recommended approach.

Comment: looks like it doesn't handle segues, it works with only links? I want to open the matched word in new vc

Comment: You can push a segue when a link is tapped in `shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`, if you can get links to work, but otherwise you'll have to go with #2.

Comment: this looks pretty cool https://github.com/evilBird/HBVLinkedTextView but its objective c

Answer (score 0):

For future googlers, you could use **NSLinkAttributeName**

```
attributedText.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "\(your_value)", range: matchRange)
```