# Can I get the position of elements in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

[image]

I use NSAttributeString to get something like above(include normal text ,underlined text and images) , and now I want do : if the user tapped on the underlined text area , I will do some special actions (open the web or sth). Now i can get the location of touches already , but can i find the locations (or area) of the underlined text ? so I can use both area to judge the tap position is located on underline text or not?

Comment: What component did you use? `UITextView` or `UILabel`?

Comment: Now , I was using UILabel to draw the NSAttributeString

Comment: It would be much easier to display and handle tapping on a link with `UITextView`. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/21630187/2168557 on how to use attributed string for links. Then in the `UITextViewDelegate`, implement `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` to handle tapping on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITextView` it is easy to implement. Add tap gesture on textview and when tap on textview check if tap on specific character or not.

```
textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
[textView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
textView.attributedText = @"your attributedString";
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textTapped:)];
[textView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Add Gesture implementation method

```
- (void)textTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;

    /*--- Get range of string which is clickable ---*/
    NSRange range = [textView.text rangeOfString:@"Your Clickable String"];

    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = textView.layoutManager;
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:textView];
    NSUInteger characterIndex = [layoutManager characterIndexForPoint:location inTextContainer:textView.textContainer fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:NULL];

    if (characterIndex >= range.location && characterIndex < range.location + range.length - 1)
    {
        NSLog(@"Text Tapped:");
    }
}
```

Comment: AMAZING. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you can UItextview and its delegate will help.

Step 1

```
{
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.sina.com"];
NSMutableAttributedString * str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:"Your text to display"];
[str addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value:URL range: NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
_textview.attributedText = str;
}
```

Step 2
Add delegate

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
   NSLog(@"URL:: %@",URL);
  //You can do anything with the URL here (like open in other web   view).
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL];
return YES;
}
```

Step 3 Editable (No),Selectable (Yes), Links is optional

[image: Please tick following properties from textview]

Hope it will help you..!

Answer (score 0):

you can use html string in attribute string like this:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```