# UITextView on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a tricky problem here.

A `UITextView` is a subview of `UITableViewCell.

The `UITextView` receives touch event and `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` isn't invoked.

I know I can get the tableView's event if I set `userInteraction:NO` to UITextView. However, the `UITextView`'s content is `NSAttributedString` and the string has `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute. If I set `userInteraction` to false, I can't get the `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`.

Is there any good way to be enabled both events together?

Comment: Set your `UITextView` property `editable` to `FALSE` and its `userInteraction` to `TRUE`?

Comment: do you have section in this tableView? or is it all in one section?

Comment: @Larme `UITextView` shouldn't be `editable` in my case.

Comment: @YuviGr I have 3~5 sections in case of data.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472073/can-i-get-the-position-of-elements-in-nsattributedstring/28472900#28472900) check this link it will help you

Comment: In a nutshell, no. The text field is the responder to the users touch and so invalidates the tableView. Why can't you simply call didSelectRowAtIndexPath yourself if you are relying on code in there as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `subClass` of the `UITextView` and add two variables

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger row;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger section;
```

that will hold the section number and row number. With these properties you can use `delegation/KVO` to the tell the `viewController` that a cell in (row:x & section:y) was selected.

**EDIT**

This edit is updated from @Daniel Galasko comment.

A better way to solve this is using the method `indexPathForRowAtPoint:` like so:

set the viewController to be the UITextView's delegate, and in the dekegate method

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   CGPoint position = [textView convertPoint:CGPointZero toView: <yourtableView> ];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [<your tableView> indexPathForRowAtPoint: position];
}
```

Comment: Thats silly, imagine you had multiple different views in a cell. you would have to do this for every view. Why not use the indexPathForRowAtPoint method...

Comment: where would you use this method?!

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577392/uitextfield-subview-of-uitableviewcell-get-indexpath-of-cell/27938042#27938042 once you have the textView you can easily get its index path assuming you also have access to the table view

Comment: yes i can see how that could work thanks ill update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get a cell why don't user superview ?

For instance, when you select your textBox, you can say something like

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)textView.superview.superview;
}
```

Note that you need it twice, once for content view and next for tableview cell.

Here is reference for UITableView hierarchy:
http://www.curiousfind.com/blog/646

Also, take care when you are dealing with ios8 since I think they added additional layer. Because of that you could do something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)getCellForTextView:(UIView*)searchForView
{
    if(search isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]){
        return search;
    }
    if(!search)
       return NULL;
    return [self getCellForTextView:search.superview];
}
```

and in you function you can do:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
    {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [self getCellForTextView:textView];
       if(cell) 
       {
          //do stuff
       }
       else 
       {
            //it is null! handle this somehow
       }
    }
```