# SLComposeViewController setinitial text using hyperlink

Tags: ios, hyperlink, slcomposeviewcontroller

I want to set initial text of SLComposeViewController but couldn't find a way to include hyperlink in between the text e.g.

[faceBookSheetSheet setInitialText:@"Shared via Wassay iOS app"];

I want that when posted "Wassay" should appear as a hyperlink/clickable text which i can redirect it to my home page.

Comment: You need to set attributed string.  This link may be helpful [make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a-uitextfield-or-uilabel][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a-uitextfield-or-uilabel

Comment: Have you tried it? will it post to my Facebook page making Wassay clickable??