# how to make clickable link in alert controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

[image: My app screenshot]

I want alert dialog box like this image. which contains a clickable link like blue highlighted text. when user click on that text, it will open a link in browser. For this i am using third party library [SimpleAlert](https://github.com/KyoheiG3/SimpleAlert)

here is my code...

```
func popUpMsg(){

    let msg = "\n Hi Rahul! Welcome back to the early access queue for the app, Once you've been accepted into the beta, we'll notify you using the contact info you have on file with Facebook. \n\n But just a second, if you haven't already done so, you can increase your odds of jumping ahead in the queue by telling us a little about yourself. Please complete our 4-question survey to give it a shot. \n" as NSString
    let range = msg.rangeOfString("complete our 4-question survey")

    let alert = SimpleAlert.Controller(title: "Early Access to Application", message: msg as String, style: .Alert)
    alert.configContentView = { view in
        if let view = view as? SimpleAlert.ContentView {
            view.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            view.titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(32)
            print(view.titleLabel.font)
            view.messageLabel.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()

            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: msg as String)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!, range: range)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(int: 1), range: range)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.whiteColor(), range: range)

            view.messageLabel.attributedText = attributedString
            view.messageLabel.font = UIFont(name: "arial", size: 27)
            print(view.messageLabel.font)

            view.textBackgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
            view.textBackgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
    alert.addAction(SimpleAlert.Action(title: "OK", style: .OK))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: So what's your problem ?

Comment: Why don't you redirect the actual page while click on OK button ? It is better  for programming rather than link in alert view.

Comment: you are correct but this is not my client requirement...

Comment: Then explain to your client that Apple has guidelines for User Experience and tell him that is always best to follow those. (even if those guidelines say nothing about a link in text in an alert) Educating the client is part of a developers job.

Comment: Guidelines or not, I'd also like to be able to make hyperlinks within the message text of a UIAlertController, with the `OK` button reserved for making the controller go away.   I can already create the links, but they're not (yet) clickable.

Comment: @Rahulsingh Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: @AsthaGupta ..... Yes, i found..instead of UILabel use UITextView. Add NSLinkAttributeName 
 attribute and then use UITextView delegate method : 
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool { ...  }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/how-to-make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a Refer this link