# swift: Set the hyperlink on the Text

Tags: ios, swift, hyperlink

I am trying to set Hyperlink in the text. Text appears but i cannot find the link on the text. Can anyone help here.
I want to set the link on **My Health Action Plan** on getStartedDict. but only whole text appears without any links.

```
let link1 = ["My Health Action Plan"]
var getStartedDict =
   ["":"Now that you have a glimpse of where you currently are in managing your health, it is time for you to update your Health Action Plan. Use the information in the Health Profile along with the online resources in this portal to help set realistic health goals and to help you work toward better health."]
var linkArray = [[String]]()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    linkArray.removeAll()
    linkArray.append(link1)
    CommonUtility.sharedInstance.addBackButton(self)
    loadData()
 }
```

//here i tried to set the link

```
  if let getStartedText = self.getStartedDict[self.model.label1]?.htmlStringToAttributedString()
        {
            let aText = getStartedText
            let myRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: aText.length)
            aText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(kFontSize), range: myRange)
            print(aText)
            cell.detail.setLinksForSubstrings(linkArray, withLinkHandler: handler)

        }
```

**Updated: Refer to comment for answer**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28572505/6271729 have you tried this?

Comment: yes i have looked over it but did succed..will you help me out

Comment: you can help me through that approach also

Comment: use Attributed String to make your text as hyperlink

Comment: can you comment so that i can understand more

Answer (score 0):

finally after long hours of Headache i have done this:

```
var getStartedDict =
   ["Value":"Now that you have a glimpse of where you currently are in managing your health, it is time for you to update your Health Action Plan. Use the information in the Health Profile along with the online resources in this portal to help set realistic health goals and to help you work toward better health."]

 override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        CommonUtility.sharedInstance.addBackButton(self)
        loadData()
     }
```

**This is how we can set the link**

```
if let getText = self.getStartedDict["Value"]?.htmlStringToAttributedString(){
        let aText = getText
        let myRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: aText.length)
        aText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(kFontSize), range: myRange)
        cell.detail.attributedText = aText
        cell.detail.setLinksForSubstrings(["Health Action Plan"], withLinkHandler: handler)
    }
    else{
        print("No text found")
    }
```

Fell free to comment in case, if there is a better way for this.