# How to make two or more strings in UILabel text point to different links

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, xcode8.2

I have a UILabel which shows the String. I need to change the color of the particular texts in the UILabel and when clicking on those texts it should open two different links in a webview. How to achieve this:
The following code i have written:

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is Yahoo and Google" attributes:nil];
  [attributedString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                    value: [UIColor redColor]
                    range: NSMakeRange(8,5)];


  [attributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                    value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]
                    range: NSMakeRange(8,5)];

  [attributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName
                    value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Didot" size:24]
                    range: NSMakeRange(18,6)];

  self.linkLabel.attributedText  = attributedString;

}
```

Now i want when the user clicks on google it should open google.com and when the user taps Yahoo it should open yahoo.com. how is ti possible?

Comment: why don't you use two button instead ?

Comment: use two buttons next to each other

Comment: refer to this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/how-to-make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring-for-a Hope it will be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change to UITextView and it should use the following

```
    let verbiage = links.text! // UITextView text
    let attributes = NSMutableAttributedString(string: verbiage)

    let googleRange = (verbiage as NSString).range(of: "Google")
    let yahooRange = (verbiage as NSString).range(of: "Yahoo")

    attributes.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "https://www.google.com", range: googleRange)
    attributes.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "https://www.yahoo.com", range: yahooRange)

    let linkAttributes: [String : Any] = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red,
        NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: UIColor.clear,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone.rawValue]

    links.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
    links.attributedText = attributes
```

Do not forget set Scrolling Enabled to false and Editable to false in order to get UITextView similar to UILabel

Answer (score 1):

Use below line to add link to your text before assigning attributedString

```
 [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSUrl urlwithString@"https://www.google.com"] range:NSMakeRange(18,6)];
```

Similarly you can do for other strings as well.