# How to make tappable NSAttributedString Move To Another ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsattributedstring, nsattributedstringkey

I'm working on a simple app and add programatically `NSAttributedString`.
I am really confused how to move present `viewcontroller` to another `viewcontroller`.

This is not duplicate question because my question for how move  to view controller and duplicatie question how to open link on click 
 [How can I make a clickable link in an NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/how-can-i-make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring).

**Screen shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

In above image show three `NSAttributedString` first one is `dhiman.sham1gmail.com` and second one is`has started following` and third one `Sham`. When trying to click on `Sham` no action perform. i want to move this controller to another controller when click on `Sham` .

**This is my Code:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLbl: UILabel!

override func updateWithModel(_ model: AnyObject) {
 self.descriptionLbl.attributedText = self.followingGetTextFromType(data: (model as? FollowingNotificationData)!)
}

func followingGetTextFromType(data:FollowingNotificationData) -> NSMutableAttributedString{
  var attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
  attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:(data.detailsNoti?.fullName)!, attributes: strres)
  let startedfollowing = NSMutableAttributedString(string:" has started following ", attributes: attrs)
  attributedString.append(startedfollowing)
  var discription = NSMutableAttributedString()
  if data.fullName == ""{
  discription = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\((data.userName)!)", attributes: strres)
  }else{
  discription = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\((data.fullName)!)", attributes: strres)
  }
  attributedString.append(discription)
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how to solve this , i've tried to solve this issue but no results yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apple Documentation on `NSAttributedString.Key.link`: The value of this attribute is an NSURL object (preferred) or an NSString object. The default value of this property is nil, indicating no link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a clickable link in an NSAttributedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629784/how-can-i-make-a-clickable-link-in-an-nsattributedstring)

Comment: @0xa6a yes i know very well but please tell me how to view controller move click on attributeString

Comment: @0xa6a this is for a link Open not for ViewController i am just trying to use this but not give any solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code to make `NSMutableAttributedString`, You can make it dynamic as your requirement to pass dynamic string value as a parameter.

Put `UItextView` insted of `UIlabel`

```
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLbl: UITextView!

descriptionLbl.attributedText = prepareAttributedTextString()

func prepareAttributedTextString() -> NSMutableAttributedString {

        let masterString = "dhiman@gmail.com has started following Sham"

        let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: masterString)

        let ShamUseAttribute = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
            NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0),
            NSAttributedStringKey.link: URL(string: "Sham")!,
            ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]


        let ShamRange = (masterString as NSString).range(of: "Sham")
        formattedString.addAttributes(ShamUseAttribute, range: ShamRange)

        return formattedString
    }
```

Use this `UITextViewDelegate` to detect tap on `UItextView` and predict to specified `UIviewController`

```
// MARK: UITextView Delegate Method
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

       if (URL.absoluteString == "Sham") { 
             let objVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController           
             self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objVC, animated: true)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Set following property from the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Atul Sir please explain this line:         formattedString.addAttributes(formattedStringAttribute, range: NSMakeRange(0, formattedString.length))
 and also not here any name of valriable `formattedStringAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

You have two option to make things work as per your requirements easily either User below `UILabel` library or change your control to `UITextView`.

I found great library for UILabel class, this will surely help you. I did this same thing by using this.

1. UILabel

   [[TTTAttributedLabel]](http://%20https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i want to move ViewController not open URL

Comment: Sir i want to move another viewController like push Controller