# Get HTML in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I display html in `UITextView` by:

`[self.textView setValue:@"<b>Content</b>" forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];`,

After editing content in `UITextView`, I want to get content include html so I use:

`[self.textView valueForKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];` but app crash, how to fix it?

Comment: why you not use UIWebView instead of UItextView..?

Comment: i build app mail client like mail app, compose mail use UIWebview cannot reslove scroll with cursor position.

Answer (score 28):

For ios 7 use following code.

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<h1>Header</h1><h2>Subheader</h2><p>Some <em>text</em></p><img src='http://blogs.babble.com/famecrawler/files/2010/11/mickey_mouse-1097.jpg' width=70 height=100 />";
        NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
        textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [Display html text in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview)  this question Use a `UIWebView`.

Because  ***undocumented -[UITextView setContentToHTMLString:] method. App will be rejected for using undocumented methods.***

But still you want doing this you can take a look this links Might be help:-

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bctextview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/egotextview

and for doing this task with UIWebview you must look this :-

[Rich-text-editing-sample-project](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/rich-text-editing-sample-project/)

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *htmlContentString = self.compnayInfoPageDictionary[@"tDescription"];

[self.txtViewInfoPage setValue:htmlContentString forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```