# How to load HTML in UITextView?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a HTML contents with achor tag in it. I just want to load that HTML content in `UITextView`.

Comment: View this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608060/get-html-in-uitextview

Answer (score 3):

You can convert an HTML document to `NSAttributedString` like so:

```
// The HTML needs to be in the form of an NSString
NSError *error = nil;
NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[HTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %s %i", error.localizedDescription, __func__, __LINE__);
} else {
    // Clear text view
    textView.text = @"";
    // Append the attributed string
    [textView.textStorage appendAttributedString:attString];
}
```

If you come across any problems then try changing the encoding to `NSASCIIStringEncoding` in all places.