# Load HTML content to UITextView where the UIFont should be that of the UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some `HTML` content having its own styling(font and text colour) properties. I need to load this `HTML` content to a `UITextView`, but the `UITextView` loads the `HTML` content using the styling properties of the `HTML` content and not the `UIFont` and colour property of `UITextView`.

**What I need:**

I need to load the `HTML` content to `UITextView` with the `UIFont` and `textColour` properties of the `UITextView`.

Comment: show us some code what you have tried so far

Comment: You better to load your HTML content with font in WebView

Comment: i think this link will help to find your answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875315/how-to-load-html-in-uitextview?rq=1

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik This is not an exact duplicate please check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let this be the `HTML` content

```
<span style=\134"color: rgb(173, 173, 173); font-family: titilliumtitle12regular; font-size: 16px; text-transform: none; float: none; display: inline !important;\134">testing purpose Matchboxx is the first social sporting application that gives full control to sports professionals and enthusiasts who desire to set-up, manage, participate or watch sports teams in any location around the world. This, coupled with a suite of social tools which provide users with ease-of-use sport event management, provides a unique and rewarding experience to users around the world. Join today and get started!Testing</span><br>
```

This thing worked for me,

loading `HTML` content to `NSAttributedString`

```
NSString *htmlString = HTML_Content;
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData: [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options: @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error: nil];
```

Then Adding an attribute for `UIFont`

```
[attributedString addAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"nexabold" size:16.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
```

setting the `UITextView` with Attributed Text

```
txtView.text = @"";
txtView.attributedText = attributedString;
txtView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
```

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSAttributedString' declares the selector 'addAttributes:range:'

Answer (score 0):

// try like this

```
NSString *text = textView.text;

// This will give me an attributedString with the base text-style
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor redColor]
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, text.length)];

textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UIWebView *webView  = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[webView loadHTMLString:@"your string" baseURL:nil];
[yourTextView addSubview:webView];
```