# How to display HTML data in UITextview or UIView in ios

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitextview

How to display html data in UITextview or uiview.This is my html data

{\"id\":\"4\",\"title\":\"Predictions proved correct in the year 2013\",\"description\":\"*<\/font> Financial system in America for this year is not indicated progress this year too. More problems will creep up.
\r\n*<\/font> Aggressive stage of Telangaana agitation- formation of seperate Telangaana state- bifurcation of state - sure indications are \r\n\r\npredicted.
\r\n*<\/font> Bad days for congress party was predicted long back. The same situations will continue.
\r\n*<\/font> The Gujarath CM - Sri Narendra Modi - Bright future is indicated. ( Care should be taken on health aspects).
\r\n*<\/font> Still danger is indicated for Indoneshia and Sumitra Islands.
\r\n*<\/font> Man is weak before nature. Proved again and again.\r\nEarthquakes, Earth movement, merceless sun, oceans\/seas through out the world causing havocs, hub for disputes, falling of meteriorids, water havocs\r\n- are indicated. --- Prayers to Gods, Bhoosuktam chanting, --- Following of rites are needed.}

i want to display like this in UITextview or UIView.

- Financial system in America for this year is not indicated progress this year too. More problems will creep up.
- Aggressive stage of Telangaana agitation- formation of seperate Telangaana state- bifurcation of state - sure indications are predicted.
- Bad days for congress party was predicted long back. The same situations will continue.
- The Gujarath CM - Sri Narendra Modi - Bright future is indicated.

using Json parser how get the html data and how to display response data in UITextview or uiview.please help me any body.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview

Comment: I provided some pointers for working with JSON and HTML, but your data does not look like HTML, so that is likely to cause problems.

Comment: Narendra Modi is great...:)

Comment: Help me any body...............

Comment: i cant understand how to do this.........

Comment: you can try to extract it as RSS and then parse the XML. Why are you trying to show the complete HTML data including tags? You can't parse them exactly you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) — a subclass of `UIView` — and its method `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`. You might also find [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

YES you can parse HTML content of file.

If you want to get specific value from `HTML` content you need to **Parce** `HTML` content by using [`Hpple`](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple). Also This is [documentation with exmple](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)  that are is for parse `HTML`. Another way is **rexeg** but it is more complicated so this is best way in your case.