# HTML to NSMutableAttributedString not working in ios 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring

I am using below code to convert HTML text into NSMutableAttributedString and showing it in UITextView. -

```
attributedStringTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[titleString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

This is working fine for iOS 7 or later but not working on iOS 6.. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is not available in iOS6:

From the Apple docs:

> NSHTMLTextDocumentType Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) document.
>
> Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: Look for 3rd party libraries, check CocoaPods.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` is only available on iOS 7 and later. Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Document_Types) for the list of available constants.

Comment: Look for a 3rd party framework, or handle manually the components from the HTML doc

Answer (score 1):

As per Docs `NSHTMLTextDocumentType is only available on iOS 7 and later` So there are some alternatives which you can do:-

1)For this you can use a `3rd party Framework`.

2)Use `UIWebView`

3)Refer this [display-html-text-in-uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview)

But if you only need to parse html tags into strings then you can use `initWithString` api for your workaround. But before that you need to create the string object str from NSData using `initWithData`:-

```
- (NSString *)initWithData:(NSData *)data encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)str attributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs;
```

**Note:- The above two api will parse html tags as a plain text**