# How do I create a NSAttributedString from HTML in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, swift3

I have an HTML string and I want to make an `NSAttributedString` out of it. This is fairly simple in Objective-C:

```
NSData* html;
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:html documentAttributes:nil];
```

This should be fairly simple in Swift as well, but I apparently can't get it right. I have this:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

let html: Data = ...
let str = NSAttributedString(HTML: html, documentAttributes: nil)
```

However, this causes an error:

```
error: repl.swift:5:11: error: ambiguous use of 'init(HTML:documentAttributes:)'
let str = NSAttributedString(HTML: html, documentAttributes: nil)
          ^

found this candidate
found this candidate
```

This is from the REPL, but Xcode gives the same error. Of course, "found this candidate" refers to `<unknown>:0`, so I have no idea where the ambiguity is coming from.

How do I create a `NSAttributedString` from HTML data in Swift 3.0?

Comment: `let str = try? NSAttributedString(data: html, options: [:], documentAttributes: nil)` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28532609/2303865

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28416599/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus, are you meaning to say that there is no way to call the documented overload that takes no `options` parameter?

Comment: @LeoDabus I don't think stackoverflow.com/a/28532609/2303865 and stackoverflow.com/a/28416599/2303865 are a duplicate. They just demonstrate another way of calling `NSAttributedString` that happens to get around this issue. It's a different problem.

Comment: @Hlung If you would like me to reopen the question please let me know

Comment: @zneak There's another initializer that has options param and it has a default value `[:]` when not given: `init?(html data: Data, options: [AnyHashable : Any] = [:], documentAttributes dict: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSDictionary?>?)` I think that's the cause. I don't know if there's a way to call the overloaded version. :(

Comment: The other thing that annoys me greatly about this problem is that, at least on my machine, swift can't say which overloads are conflicting.