# How to transfer HTML text into an attributed string without losing line breaks in Swift 3

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

Please do not mark as duplicate. None of the existing questions solves *not losing line breaks*.

Given String: `"Regular text becomes <b>bold with&nbsp;</b>\n\n<b><i>An italic</i></b>\n\n<b>Linebreak</b>"`

I have two options:

```
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
        data: story.body.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
        options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                   NSFontAttributeName: Handler.shared.setFont(FontNames.sourceSerifProRegular, 25.0)],
        documentAttributes: nil)
```

This option loses the font, size **and** the line breaks.

The following [extension from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30711288/5896501), keeps `UILabel`'s font, but it loses the line breaks as well.

```
extension UILabel {
    func _slpGetSize() -> CGSize? {
        return (text as NSString?)?.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    }

    func setHTMLFromString(htmlText: String) {
        let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: \(self.font!.fontName); font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, htmlText) as String

        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: modifiedFont.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)

        self.attributedText = attrStr
    }
}

label.setHTMLFromString(htmlText: story.body)
```

What am I missing? What do I need to do to keep the line breaks?
Help is very appreciated.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have tried changing `using: .unicode` to `using: .utf8`, same.

Comment: I have just updated the answer. If you use it properly it will work.

Comment: @LeoDabus still not working

Comment: If you use the extension just use `yourHTMLCode.data.attributedString`

Comment: define what `not working` means

Comment: the text is bold and italic, but the line breaks are missing.

Comment: what is the original string? the given string ?

Comment: yes, the provided string

Comment: html line break is `<br>` not `\n`

Comment: okay well. that solves that, huh. @LeoDabus since you seem super fit in that, can you tell me, to change the space between lines `using my code`, what do i have to add?

Comment: just add `<br><br>` :)

Comment: i have already done that, worked like a charm, but now the spacing between the lines is big af. any ideas?

Comment: @DavidSeek I got a solution, you can replace \n character with <br> tag before converting HTML text into an attributed string.  For instance, here you can do the following story.body.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "<br>") . Now you can safely convert HTML text into an attributed string.

Comment: To retain the font and size you can use let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
                data: story.body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
                options: [ .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                           NSFontAttributeName: Handler.shared.setFont(FontNames.sourceSerifProRegular, 25.0)],
                documentAttributes: nil)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try set numberOfLines property in the UILabel.

For that, you can count the number of break lines and set into numberOfLines.

```
extension UILabel {
    func _slpGetSize() -> CGSize? {
        return (text as NSString?)?.size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    }

    func setHTMLFromString(htmlText: String) {
        let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: \(self.font!.fontName); font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, htmlText) as String

        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: modifiedFont.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)

        self.attributedText = attrStr

        self.numberOfLines = htmlText.components(separatedBy: "\n").count
    }
}
```

I hope this example help you.

Comment: doesn't help. unfortunately

Comment: I've just test this code and works fine to me. What's happened?