# How to render HTML(tags,images both) in iOS? Which component to go with?

Tags: html, ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

So, the scenario is I want to render a HTML string which can contain anything I mean text,images etc. And I have to show it in some control(UIWebView,UITextview,UILabel) as a cell in UITableView. Since i am making an e-book kind of app, lets say Kindle. Tell me how to go with this. Please keep this in mind on long-press, I have to show UIMenuControl also; to give options like highlight,copy,bookmark. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please post an example of what you have tried and specifically what you would like help with, since we cannot write your whole application for you.  Based on your description, it sounds like you want a `UIWebView` with a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.  However, you cannot really embed a `UIWebView` inside a table cell.

Comment: @Eric then what is the best way to render the html rich content in ios?

Comment: Depends on what you want.  Based on what you're describing, you probably want a `UIWebView`.  However, you can create an `NSAttributedString` from HTML text, which supports a limited set of HTML content but can be used in a `UILabel`, `UITextView`, etc.  See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20996085/358696).

Comment: @EricGalluzzo The thing i have to show images also, how to show images in textview? 

I have to make KINDLE kind of app, i need to show the e-book whose data i am getting from API's call page by page in the form of HTML.

Comment: `NSAttributedString` supports images via `NSTextAttachment`.  Again, you should be able to construct an `NSAttributedString` from HTML (see link in previous answer).  However, if you are really making a Kindle style app, I'm not sure why you would need a `UITableView`.  I'd use a `UIWebView` instead, or possibly two, one for each page.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo UIWebView will not give the native feel i believe, there would be problems regarding GPU while scrolling.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean.  If you want to display HTML content, you would generally use a `UIWebView`.  I would agree that using a `UIWebView` for your main UI -- i.e. creating a "hybrid" app with buttons, menus, tables and so forth all represented in the HTML -- is not generally recommended as it does not give you a native app look and feel without a lot of effort.  I'm sure that Apple has designed iOS to use the GPU while scrolling any native component when possible, including `UIWebView`.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo  When i am putting UIWebView in a UITableView, then I am finding a problem in resizing the size of the cell, since it is not supporting AutoLayout feature..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, at last, I go with the UIWebView only and with the help of javascript and jquery I managed to achieve what I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of embedding a web view in a table view cell:

http://gkbrown.org/2016/01/15/embedding-a-web-view-in-a-table-view-cell-using-markupkit/

The example uses the open-source [MarkupKit](https://github.com/gk-brown/MarkupKit) framework to simplify the construction of the view.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Greg but height is still fixed.

Comment: That's correct - web views don't have an intrinsic content size. If you want the web view to appear in a table view cell, you will need to give it a fixed height. If a table view is not strictly required, there are other layout options that will allow the web view to dynamically resize.

Comment: Tableview is not strictly required, pls guide me with other layouts?

Comment: The simplest approach would probably be to put a web view in a navigation controller. You could put your controls in the navigation bar or toolbar, and the web view will be automatically sized to fill the remaining space.

If that is not sufficient, you could use auto layout to create a custom view arrangement. MarkupKit can definitely help with this. Let me know if you need any additional information.