# Displaying HTML content in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to display the String HTML in a UITextView control using swift. I found some code and tried it:

```
     do {
        let str = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

but i gives some error i am unable to understand or found any solution, which states as,

**Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'**

I need to figure out why i am having this error. Any solution or alternate code?
The other solutions are in objective-c if they either have answers they are giving the same error i tried many just because of old versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display html text in uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview)

Comment: Swift 4 introduced new "keys": NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute vs `NSAttributedString.someKey` You are using the old one, and what looks like more of Objective-C one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This

```
var attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: "<b><i>text</i></b>".data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options:[NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)
        YOUR_TEXTVIEW.attributedText = attrStr
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `options` to

```
let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
```

So it should be:

```
 do {
    let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
    let str = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it is properly working for me

```
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: htmlText.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, 
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)
```

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey' already explained in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   let htmlString = "<html><body> Some html string </body></html>";

    do {
        let str = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)

        self.txView.attributedText  = str

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```