# How to open a HTML file in the apple tv app?

Tags: html, webkit, tvos

I am working on a tvOS app and I need to open a HTML file in the app. This HTML file is available locally in the app bundle. How can I open such file in the tv app as WebKit is not available in the tv app

Comment: There's no way to display HTML as there is no web view available on tvOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no web browser or even WKWebView available in tvOS.

Nevertheless to display simple HTML content as Privacy Policies or similar... you could still use UITextView as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454067/display-html-text-in-uitextview/20996085#20996085)