# Can iphone's labels, textfields or other UI elements accept HTML formatted text and display it correctly?

Tags: iphone, html, uitextfield, uilabel

Is there any trick so i can give html formatted text to e.g. UILabel or UITextField and iphone will format the text accordingly?

For example if there is a bold tag, the text will be bolded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

To display HTML you need to use a UIWebView. If you want a rich text editor then you need to look at 3rd party Such as three20. Or on iOS > 4 you can use contentEditable in a UIWebView

Comment: I can't find a method called 'contentEditable' in UIWebView... what is it?

Comment: It isn't a method, it is a HTML property. So you would put your HTML inside an element with contentEditable set to true, e.g.: `<div contenteditable="true"><b> some html </b> to display</div>`

Answer (score 1):

No, the only class I know in iOS that displays HTML is UIWebView. Of course, you can use a small web view to display some HTML to get text styles. But if you're only want to draw static styled text in a view you can use CoreText. There are many examples out there (including one from Apple called CoreTextPageViewer) of how to draw an NSAttributedString with CoreText.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

try with NSAttributedString.

https://nodeload.github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/zipball/master

inthis example ,they show on UILable

Answer (score 1):

You can try with NSAttributedString

```
label.attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
          initWithData: [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
               options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
    documentAttributes: nil
                 error: &err];
```

Answer (score 0):

Only UIWebView supports html but you should also checkout this repo on github -

https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better way display HTML content in UIwebview  compare to handle in other component

Comment: Our customers want to have some control over how certain parts of the app look, so we were considering this option because Android has some good classes for this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Comment: We were thinking about letting them put their html on server and fetching it with our android/iphone apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HTML String content for UILabel and TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261654/html-string-content-for-uilabel-and-textview)
Where he mentions about "Three20 project which includes a class TTStyledTextLabel which allows you to render HtmL-Code and even activates links"